# regex- how to stop at first occurrence of a character

Tags: java, c#, php, regex, perl

I am trying to extract the src value from a  tag,
so far I seem to be able to extract the string between the src value and the final quotation mark in the string

**String:**

```
<img  border="0"  src="http://i.bookfinder.com/about/booksellers/logo_borderless/amazon_uk.gif" width="89" height="31" alt="">
```

**e.g. in PHP:**

```
preg_match('/src=\"(.*)\"/', $row->find('a img',0), $matches);
if($matches){
   echo $matches[0];
}
```

**prints out** 
`src="http://i.bookfinder.com/about/booksellers/logo_borderless/amazon_uk.gif" width="89" height="31" alt=""`

**but what i really want printed is...**
`src="http://i.bookfinder.com/about/booksellers/logo_borderless/amazon_uk.gif"`

**or if possible just...**
`http://i.bookfinder.com/about/booksellers/logo_borderless/amazon_uk.gif`

what should I be adding to the regex? Thanks

Comment: See my answer below to learn where you made a mistake.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For RegExp:

```
preg_match('/src="([^"]+)"/', $row->find('a img',0), $matches);
echo $matches[1];
```

If i'm right, you are working with **simple_html_dom_parser** library. If that's true you can just type:

```
$row->find('a img',0)->src
```

Comment: +1 for the `$row->find('a img',0)->src`, I was hoping this would be possible.

Answer (score 11):

You were actually very close >>

```
Yours:        preg_match('/src=\"(.*)\"/',  $row->find('a img',0), $matches);
Correct one:  preg_match('/src=\"(.*?)\"/', $row->find('a img',0), $matches);
```

By adding `?` you make request for match `.*` lazy, which means it will match anything until needed, not anything until can. Without lazy operator it will stop in front of last double-quote `"`, which is behind `alt="`.

Comment: /[^"]+/ works faster because it's greedy. You can use this one regexp because it's impossible that image url will contain quote.

Comment: @Serjio - Serjio, welcome on SO. I am VERY GOOD in regex and I certainly agree with you about performance, as lazy operator shold be omit if possible. The point here, what I wanted to do by my answer, is to get OP some lesson. As you can see, my answer was posted after `[^"]+` has been suggested, so I didn't want to be a jerk and post same regex with no help. Explanation of lazy operator should be important to learn for OP.

Comment: Thanks I'll keep that in mind, I've just started reading up on regex

Comment: @Ωmega ok i'm sorry. I didn't want to provoke you. But as you wrote, now everybody will see the difference between lazy and greedy regexp and will know why i have used greedy one.

Comment: Nice to compare the two regex, makes finding a difference easier.
didn't know about the lazy operator, just helped me solve my regex. thanks(+1) :)

Answer (score 4):

try, it should be good for your needs

```
/src=\"[^\"]+\"/
```