# php regex - match only for 1 occurrence don't match for more than one

Tags: php, regex

I am trying to write regex that will catch this phrase:
`background: url("../images/btn-send.png") no-repeat scroll -70px center rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);`
but not this:
`background: url("../images/btn-send.png") no-repeat scroll -70px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);`

so I should get match only on `...<number>px ...` and not
 `...<number>px <number>px ....`

I have tried to use the next regex:
`background\s*:[^;]*?((-*\d+px|0)\s+){1}[a-z]`
I am using it in PHP `preg_match`

I had tried to find only one occurrence of px, but it's not working and it's matching both of the strings, can you please help me with that?
Thank!

Comment: I think you mean `b{1}a{1}c{1}k{1}g{1}r{1}o{1}u{1}n{1}d{1}`...? `</pull what="leg">`

Comment: not I am trying to catch only strings that have `background:<any letters><number>px(appears once!)<any letters>;` but not `background:<any letters><number>px(appears twice)<any letters>;`

Comment: You could use something like `'/background\s*:[^;]*?((?<!\dpx|0) (-*\d+px|0)\s+)[a-z]/i`, but that requires normalize spaces (only 1 space may seperate them, not tabs, other whitespace, or several spaces. Can you normalize the string there (in other words, can you `preg_replace('/\s+/',' ',$string);` beforehand, or does that destroy significant whitespace?

Comment: I believe the answer to [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11302717/2171102) question is what you were looking for.

Comment: @user2979757: oh, and @tripleee was trying to say `{1}` is useless, you can omit that, it does not make it 'invalid' if it could match more times, it just says to match it one time if possible.

Comment: thanks @echochamber I already red this answer but it's no use, I had tries to put `?` in several places but it's still not working..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pending a more elegant answer (I'm not entirely convinced by this one), this would work:

```
<?php
$str1 = 'background: url("../images/btn-send.png") no-repeat scroll -70px  center rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);';
$str2 = 'background: url("../images/btn-send.png") no-repeat scroll -70px   10px   rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);';

var_dump(preg_match('/background\s*:[^;]*?((?<!\dpx|0|\s)\s+(-*\d+px|0)\s+)[a-z]/i',$str1));
var_dump(preg_match('/background\s*:[^;]*?((?<!\dpx|0|\s)\s+(-*\d+px|0)\s+)[a-z]/i',$str2));
```

So, what does `(?<!\dpx|0|\s)\s+` do? Is says your Npx/0 should be proceded by at least one whitespace character, but maybe more, not preceded by (`(?<!...)`) either whitespace (ensuring it matches from the first whitespace character when there are several), another `Npx`, or `0`.

Comment: Thank you, I've changed it somewhat now though (`(?<!\dpx|0|\s)\s+` works just as well, the `\s\s+` turned out to be a leftover from a previous try/iteration).